# Google Play java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-play, noclassdeffounderror

I've been battling this for a good few days now, have scoured Stack Overflow for similar topics, tried many things, but cannot put my finger on this failing test in Google Play. I thought I was whittling it down by gradually modifying bits of code, however more recently found that I can run the same build multiple times and it will pass and fail at random!

It's always the Galaxy S3 on Android 4.3, which is the lowest I support. All other devices pass.

Please help :)

[image: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError]

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-878
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.uiautomator.UiAutomatorInteractionController.launchPackage(UiAutomatorInteractionController.java:41)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridInteractionController.launchPackage(HybridInteractionController.java:48)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:42)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.performAction(RemotePlatform.java:67)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.handlePerformAction(RemotePlatform.java:19)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.messageLoop(RemotePlatform.java:61)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.lambda$startCrawlAndWaitUntilFinished$0$RemotePlatform(RemotePlatform.java)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Any updates, I also got the same error, and I am also stuck :(

Comment: Afraid not :( I don't have any reports from Production usage though, only Google Play tests... so I'm not too worried right now as customers are happy. Would be good to get to the bottom of it though.